# Bootstrap Toggle menu not working in mobile view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I created a testing file using bootstrap. I called the bootstrap.min.css in the head section of the webpage.

Also, I called few JavaScript files before closing the body tag.

But now as I want to create a toggle menu this will become a drop down menu when seen in mobile version, the toggle button is not working. Here is the code of Toggle button.

I want to know that what is the reason behind that. Why the toggle button is not working correctly?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Testing of Bootstrap</title>
<meta name-"viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/user/Testing/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-ctoggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Themes<b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-header">Admin & Dashboard</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</div>

<h1>Testing H1</h1>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 3</div>
  <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 5</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 6</div>
  <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 7</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 9</div>
  <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 10</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 11</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 12</div>

 </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/home/user/Testing/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Image link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRBaV.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is typo mistake in your code which I corrected it. You wrote **'data-ctoggle'** instead **data-toggle**

**Correct code:**    `<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">`

```html
    

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Testing of Bootstrap</title>
    <meta name-"viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/navbar.css">
     
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" >
     <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Themes<b class="caret"></b></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-header">Admin & Dashboard</li>
         </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
     
    </nav>

    <h1>Testing H1</h1>
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 1</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 2</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 3</div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 4</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 5</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 6</div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 7</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 8</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 9</div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 10</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 11</div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">Box 12</div>

     </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike, My example is now working. Can you please tell me, I want to overlap menus instead of sliding down of the content.

Comment: what do u mean by overlap?

Comment: I mean, the main content (start with 'Testing H1') remain fixed when clicking on the menu button. I want the menu to come over the content without sliding it down.

Comment: you can add menu as position:absolute or z-index property. that may work

Comment: Z-index is not working and getting designing issues by using 'property:absolute' .

Answer (score 0):

check this line to see if it points correctly or not

```
<script src="/home/user/Testing/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

or

Download the core files from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

Replace the javascript code as the following

```
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```